# iferror and isblank in the same expression

Tags: excel, excel-2007

How can I put isblank and iferror in the same expression. If a cell is blank or if it has an error in it, I should do something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example formula.

```
=IF(OR(ISERROR(C20),ISBLANK(C20)),"It is True", "It is False")
```

Using OR allows you to use two logical checks in the same IF. Just make sure the value in your `ISERROR` and `ISBLANK` are the same.

Replace C20 with what you are checking, and replace "It is True" with what you want to do, if it is blank or an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone, I didn't know ISERROR existed as a function, had only used IFError before.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an IF function to return an error if A1 is blank - then wrap that in ISERROR, i.e.

`=IF(ISERROR(IF(A1="",NA())),TRUE,FALSE)`

That will also return TRUE if A1 contains a blank [""] returned by a formula